# Form of the smallest vertex cover in a bipartite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm trying to write a proof of Konig's theorem using Menger's theorem. However, I got stuck along the way. In order to move forward I'd (apparently) need to show the following fact.

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with partite sets $X$ and $Y$. The smallest vertex cover of $G$ is of the form $(X-A) \cup N(A)$ for some $A \subseteq X$.

I tried doing a proof by contradiction but to no avail. Maybe the thesis I'm trying to show is false in the first place? Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be any vertex cover; let $A = X - U$ (the smallest set for which $U$ contains $X-A$).

For every vertex $b \in N(A)$, there is some edge $ab$ with $a \in A$ which needs to be covered by $U$ somehow. By construction $a \notin U$, so $ab$ is not covered by $a$. Therefore $ab$ must be covered by $b$: we must have $b \in U$. Therefore $N(A) \subseteq U$.

We have shown that $U$ contains $(X - A) \cup N(A)$. We can check that $(X - A) \cup N(A)$ is a vertex cover all by itself. Therefore if $U$ is a *minimal* vertex cover (if it has no proper subset which is a vertex cover) we must have $U = (X - A) \cup N(A)$. In particular, this is true of the smallest vertex cover.

---

I admit I do not see how you need this fact to prove Konig's theorem from Menger's theorem. Neither one deals in $N(A)$ as a concept. Maybe you are trying to prove Hall's theorem from Konig's theorem?

Comment: According to my prof, Konig's theorem states that for a bipartite graph $G$ with partite sets $X$ and $Y$, the size of a maximum a matching equals $\min_{A \subseteq X}(|X-A|+|N(A)|)$.

Comment: This is not a conventional way to state Konig's theorem. The more common statement is simply: "In a bipartite graph, the number of edges in a maximum matching is equal to the number of vertices in a minimum vertex cover."